# Can I purchase great or ultra balls?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way to purchase great balls or ultra balls? I'm on level 21 and these have been unlocked but I'm about to make my first purchase in the store and wanted to know if I could only get pokeballs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At this time you can't buy great balls or ultra balls. Besides that I highly recommend you spending the money on lucky eggs instead of poke balls, since poke balls aren't that rare.

Comment: OK so one more thing can I go over on my storage availability?  Do I have to buy an upgrade for my bag?  For example if I do buy balls and lucky eggs that was my plan maybe an incubator do I have to have to upgrade my bag to fit everything? Is it possible to go over 350?

Comment: You can't go over your storage capacity, if you wish to have more than 350 and 250 Pokemon you have to buy the upgrades. Just a friendly reminder, if you controls gyms you win pokecoins that you can spend on upgrades and poke balls.

Comment: Yeah I defeat the gym but where I live in Brooklyn it only lasts a matter of minutes before someone else defeats it so I have to collect the ten coins and wait mad long before I can collect more that's why I have in and decided to spend a few dollars.  I said I wouldn't but I gave in lol!  I'm hoping this will just give me a little head start. One more question if you don't mind would you rather incense or modules? Which is more beneficial do you think?

Comment: @CrystalMcInerney: What to buy depends on what your goals are. So, what are your goals? Mine is gym battling instead of catching Pokemon or even leveling up. Since I can only get potions from Pokestops, and I like to still have a healthy number of pokeballs to catch things, I'm spending my limited cache of coins on item space (all of my coins is from gyms) so I can hold as many potions as possible.

Answer (score -1):

There are currently two ways to obatin great and ultra balls:

1) Unlocking them at the given level (12 for great balls and 20 fors ultra balls) and thereafter as a reward for certain [level ups](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items)

2) After having hit above mentioned levels, by getting lucky spinning a PokéStop.

Comment: I suggest you read questions carefully before trying to answer them.